# width:moz-available code like this for other browsers

Tags: css

I want to use `width:moz-available` code but i think is only for mozilla firefox is any other code with same use for other brownsers? 
I want to make an object to fit all the available space.

Thank you

Comment: Post your HTML and CSS of anything that you have tried.  What you are describing sounds feasible with standard CSS.

Comment: I have a site with twiter bootstrap and i want to change the container width so i put code like that .container{width:auto;max-width1000px} but navbar dont have width like as container but smaller so i want to use width:moz-available to make it fit the container. Is posible?

Comment: You need to update your question and describe in more detail what you are trying to do.  Twitter Bootstrap changes the entire nature of your problem, so you need to add these details to your post, otherwise, it will difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: It is a responible site. And the max width of container is 980px i want to change max width to 1200px and make it fit all screen in smaller than 1200px screens so i add this code .container{width:auto;max-width1000px} and it make what i want but the navbar dont change size afte 980px. With the width:moz-available the problem solved but this code is only for firefox. So i ask if is any other css code to  make navbar fit all available space for example if the screen is 1200px the navbar must to be 1200px, if screen is 1000px the navbar must be 1000px etc.